# Proposition Logic : CNF Conversion

Tags: logic, cnf

I'm trying to solve a simple exercise in which I have to convert a propositional sentence in CNF :

This is the sentence :
**P => (Q <=> R)**

According to the resolution rule the first thing I did is to eliminate the <=> symbol in this way :

**P => (Q <=> R)**     --->      **P => (Q V R) /\ (R V Q)**

Then I removed the => symbol :

**P => (Q V R) /\ (R V Q)**    ------>    **¬P V (Q V R) /\ (R V Q)**

So my solution is  : **(¬P V Q V R) /\ (¬P V R V Q)**

While the right one is : **(¬P V ¬Q V R) /\ (¬P V ¬R V Q)**

Can anyone help me to understand where I get wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StackOverflow is intended for programming questions, which rules this question off-topic. But since I've already typed that much let me add that your first step ...

```
P => (Q <=> R) ---> P => (Q V R) ^ (R V Q)
```

is incorrect.

You know that `Q<=>R` means by definition `(Q=>R)^(R=>Q)`, right? So replacing that is the first step. Then you can use the equivalences `(Q=>R) ---> (~QvR)` and `(R=>Q) ---> (~RvQ)`.

Putting that together you should get ...

```
P => (Q <=> R) ---> P => (~Q V R) ^ (~R V Q)
```

I think you can work out the rest.